# Differing permissions according to getfacl and stat

Tags: permissions, acl

I'm pretty sure I've messed up the permissions of a directory with `setfacl`.

Before I revert everything, I'd like to understand why `getfacl` and `stat`  can give differing results for the group ownership.

`stat /run/media/mb` produces this:

```
  File: /run/media/mb/
  Size: 80          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 19580       Links: 4
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/      mb)   Gid: (  169/transmission)
Access: 2020-11-29 13:16:04.352491648 +0100
Modify: 2020-11-23 19:01:18.921787997 +0100
Change: 2020-11-23 19:40:50.176827454 +0100
Birth: -
```

Alright, the permissions of this directory grant full access to members of the group "transmission". Both `namei -olm` and `ls -l` agree with `stat`.

`getfacl /run/media/mb` disagrees:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: run/media/mb
# owner: mb
# group: transmission
user::rwx
user:mb:r-x
group::---
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

According to `getfacl`, members of the group have no access rights at all.

In effect, the user "transmission" who belongs to the group "transmission" can't access the directory:

```
sudo -u transmission ls /run/media/mb/
```

yields

```
ls: cannot open directory '/run/media/mb/': Permission denied
```

How can I reconcile the differing permissions `0775` on the one hand and `group::---` on the other? It was my assumption that those must be non-contradictory.

---

From `man 5 acl`:

> CORRESPONDENCE BETWEEN ACL ENTRIES AND FILE PERMISSION BITS
>
> The permissions defined by ACLs are a superset of the permissions specified by the file permission bits.
>
> There is a correspondence between the file owner, group, and other permissions and specific
> ACL entries: the owner permissions correspond to the permissions of the ACL_USER_OBJ entry.
> If the ACL has an ACL_MASK entry, the group permissions correspond to the permissions of the
> ACL_MASK entry.  Otherwise, if the ACL has no ACL_MASK entry, the group permissions correspond to the permissions of the ACL_GROUP_OBJ entry.  The other permissions correspond to the permissions of the ACL_OTHER_OBJ entry.
>
> **The file owner, group, and other permissions always match the permissions of the corresponding ACL entry**. Modification of the file permission bits results in the modification of the
> associated ACL entries, and modification of these ACL entries results in the modification of
> the file permission bits.

---

## Is `/run/media/mb` a link?

Doesn't seem to be: `file /run/media/mb` says, `/run/media/mb: directory` and `realpath /run/media/mb` produces `/run/media/mb`. Also `stat -L` doesn't show anything else than `stat`:

```
  File: /run/media/mb
  Size: 80          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 19580       Links: 4
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/      mb)   Gid: (  169/transmission)
Access: 2020-11-30 18:55:22.446709839 +0100
Modify: 2020-11-23 19:01:18.921787997 +0100
Change: 2020-11-23 19:40:50.176827454 +0100
Birth: -
```

## Where does `/run/media/mb` come from?

I use [`udiskie`](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie) to mount external devices on the Raspberry Pi 4. `udiskie` creates `/run/media/mb` and adds subdirectories for each external device.

Comment: Probably you have mounted some things into there, so it's hepful to include how any mounting is done, I guess this would reveal the cause of this permissions difference.

Comment: @thanasisp: udiskie does the mounting. I've added some details regarding the issue to the question.

Comment: I don't know how this program is mounting or what configuration it accepts. But it seems as an issue about mount permissions. Perhaps you could see more into the `mount` man page (about "permissions") and look into relative posts here.